# LXD Import hangs after 100%

Tags: lxd

Am I using the command line wrong?

```
me@HP-EliteDesk-20:~$ lxc project switch drupal
lxc import my_dir/mariadb_2023_01_10.export mariadb
Importing instance: 100% (1.19GB/s)  <-- this just hangs
```

Comment: context is that I have another machine on which I exported the image files.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix the problem above but did it in a similar yet different way.

Using an 'image' format to facilitate the transfer.

On source
lxc stop mariadb

```
lxc publish mariadb --alias mariadb_image

lxc image export mariadb_image

scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -r ~/exports hp-elitedesk-20:~
```

On Remote

```
lxc image import ~/exports/1876021b42ae69bff3aa44171680022412f794620ff9771d62c76b5d5dd13a54.tar.gz --alias mariadb_image

lxc image list

lxc init mariadb_image mariadb

lxc ls

lxc start mariadb
```